# Trying to write a unit test for file upload to a django Restless API

Tags: python, django, rest, file-upload, request

I'm writing a fairly small lightweight REST api so I chose restless as the quickest/easiest support for that. I didn't seem to need all the complexity and support of the django-REST module. My service will only received and send json but users need to upload files to one single endpoint. Currently my view/api code for the file upload looks like:

```
class SubmissionCreate(Endpoint):

def post(self, request):
    # get the data from the post request
    data = {}
    data['input_data'] = request.FILES['input_data'].read().decode('UTF-8')
    data['submission_name'] = request.FILES['submission_name'].read().decode('UTF-8')

    submission_form = SubmissionForm(data)
    if submission_form.is_valid():
        s = submission_form.save()
        return {'message': 'file uploaded'}
    else:
        return {'error': 'Input information is not correctly formatted'}
```

I also wrote a small client with Requests to upload files

```
import os
import requests
import json

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submission/create/'
payload = {'input_data': ('input.txt', open('./static/files/file1.txt', 'rb')), 'submission_name': 'test'}
r = requests.post(url, files=payload)
```

This works great and I can push files to the database with my client. But obviously I want some proper testing before I give this any more complex behaviour, so I looked at the docs and wrote the following test

```
class SubmissionCreateTests(TestCase):

    def test_submissioncreate_will_accept_data(self):

        f = SimpleUploadedFile("file.txt", bytes("file_content", 'utf-8'))
        response = self.client.post(reverse('submission_data'), 
                    {'input_data': f, 'submission_name': 'test'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

However this produces the following error:

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'submission_name'"
```

If I set the content_type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' I get the same error.

If I set the content_type to 'multipart/form-data' I get a 400 error but the tests run with no exception thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix this but in the end it was quicker and easier to switch to  the Django-REST framework. The docs are so much better for Djano-REST that it was trivial to set it up and build tests. There seem to be no time savings to be had with regards either the restless or django-restless modules for django.